# Create and Insert Many-to-Many Relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

First of all, i'm a beginner and trying to learn all i can. So if i have mistakes please correct me.

So, i am working on a laravel project. I've got two models; drugs and interactions. What i am struggling is, I want to add two drugs and one interaction in one form. But also, i want to check if the drug has inserted already to avoid duplicate data.

Here are my models:

```
class Drug extends Model
{
//Table Name
protected $table = 'drugs';
//Primary Key
public $primaryKey = 'id';
//Timestamps
public $timestamps = true;
//relationship
public function interactions()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Interaction', 'drug_interaction', 'interaction_id', 'drug_id');
}
}


 class Interaction extends Model
    {
    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'interactions';
    //Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    //Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;
    //Relationship
    public function drugs()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Drug', 'drug_interaction', 'drug_id', 'interaction_id');
    }
    }
```

And this is simply the store function in my DrugsController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=> 'required',
        'info'=> 'nullable'
    ]);


    //create drug
    $drug = new Drug;
    $drug->name = $request->input('name');
    $drug->info = $request->input('info');

    $drug->save();

    return redirect('/drugs')->with('success', 'İlaç Eklendi');
}
```

And this is my InterationsController's store function.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'=> 'required',
        'description'=> 'required',
        'category'=> 'nullable'
    ]);


    //create interaction
    $interaction = new Interaction;
    $interaction->name = $request->input('name');
    $interaction->description = $request->input('description');
    $interaction->category = $request->input('category');
    $interaction->save();
```

I can attach relationships via artisan tinker so i think relationship works. But i stuck when it comes to multiple input forms goes to different controllers. But using static id's. I need to make it variables. But two drugs should be attached to one interaction. So i couldn't succeed pasing two variables from form at the same time.

In dumb words, what  i am trying to achieve is;

- request drug_name_one from form's first textbox. Check db for that drug name, if exists; get its id. If it doesn't then create one and get id.
- request drug_name_two from form's second textbox. Do the same as step one.
- create an interaction as typed in form's third text box.
- attach them.

PS: after this attach() work done, i also couldn't find a way to search for two drugs if they have a common interaction. If you can also mention a few tips to achieve that i'll be grateful.

All help and further reading advices appreciated. Thanks All !

**Edit:**

This is the create_interactions migration.

```
Schema::create('interactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->BigIncrements('id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->string('description');
     $table->string('category');
     $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

This is the input for 'category' field:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('category', 'Kategori')}}
        {{Form::text('category', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Etkileşim Kategorisi'])}}
    </div>
```

I couldn't make the structure of a form as i desired btw. It's just the form for creating interactions by itself without relationship.

Comment: What type is category input?

Comment: It's a string but it is set to nullable.

Comment: I am so lost in this relationship attachment at this point, i will take care of the category field later i guess.

Comment: yh, there clearly is wrong how to do an relationship save, i need to know how the input is structured, but it is an id or a name? show example of category input.

Comment: it's a name. There is a small chance i can switch it to a dropdown select but it's still going to be a name.

Comment: I'm adding to post both migration code and the form's related part.

Comment: is it a drug category? or there is no category relationship

Comment: It is an interaction category. There is no category relationship as you said.

Comment: About relationship, just to make it clear, drugs table includes lots of drugs. Drugs with an exact number of two, matches to an interaction. An interaction row must be related to two drug rows. E.g. d1 and d2 => i1,  d1 and d3 => i2, d2 and d3 => i3 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. It is working well now.

First of all i was trying to assign 2 drugs to one interaction. So i've imported select2 and used this "select" form to list the drugs and chose multiple from them:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('İlaçları Seçin') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('drugs[]', $drugs, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control drugs']) !!}
                </div>
```

On the InteractionsController:

```
$interaction = new Interaction;

        $interaction->name = $request->input('name');
        $interaction->description = $request->input('description');
        $interaction->category = $request->input('category');

        $interaction->save();

        $interaction->drugs()->sync($request->drugs, false);
```

But i also wanted to show and edit those drugs assigned to the specific interaction. So on the edit.blade.php form there is this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.drugs').select2().val({!! json_encode($interaction->drugs()->allRelatedIds()) !!}).trigger('change');
    </script>
```

This script, calls the related drugs to the selected interaction in the same form as i used in create.blade.