# Laravel Eloquent Many to Many Search with Ajax

Tags: javascript, laravel, jquery-select2

I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858629/create-and-insert-many-to-many-relationships-in-laravel) question last week. I found the solution to add and remove related models. But this time i want to make a search.

## Database

### drugs table

```
Schema::create('drugs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->BigIncrements('id')->unique();
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->mediumText('info');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

### interactions table

```
Schema::create('interactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->BigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

### drug_interaction table

```
Schema::create('drug_interaction', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('interaction_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('interaction_id')->references('id')->on('interactions');
            $table->integer('drug_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('drug_id')->references('id')->on('drugs');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

## Models

### Drug

```
class Drug extends Model
{
    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'drugs';
    //Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    //Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function interactions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Interaction::class);
    }
}
```

### Interaction

```
class Interaction extends Model
{
    //Table Name
    protected $table = 'interactions';
    //Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    //Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;
    //Relationship
    public function drugs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Drug::class);
    }
}
```

#### InteractionsController

Since edit/update function works properly and kinda' a part of what i look for, i am only adding the update function of conrtoller.

```
public function update(Request $request, Interaction $interaction)
    {
        $interaction->name = $request->name;
        $interaction->description = $request->description;
        $interaction->category = $request->category;

        $interaction->save();

        $interaction->drugs()->sync($request->drugs);

        return redirect('/interactions')->with('success', 'Interaction Updated');
    }
```

## The Form to Add Drugs to Interactions

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {!! Form::open(['url' => 'interactions/' . $interaction->id, 'method' => 'patch']) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('name', 'Etkileşim İsmi')}}
                    {{Form::text('name', $interaction->name, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Etkileşim İsmi'])}}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('description', 'Etkileşim Açıklaması')}}
                    {{Form::textarea('description', $interaction->description, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Etkileşim Bilgisi'])}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{Form::label('category', 'Kategori')}}
                    {{Form::text('category', $interaction->category, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Etkileşim Kategorisi'])}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('İlaçları Seçin') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('drugs[]', $drugs, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control drugs']) !!}
                </div>
                {{Form::submit('Güncelle', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### select2.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drugs').select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: '25',
        minimumInputLength: '3',
        placeholder: "Etkileşimi olan 2 İlacı Seçiniz."
    });
});
```

## SearchController

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
       $drugs = Drug::pluck('name','id');
    }
```

I also have the form i used on interaction/create.blade on search.blade:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                     {!! Form::open(['url' => 'getInteraction', 'method' => 'get']) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('İlaçları Seçin') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('drugs[]', $drugs, null, ['multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control drugs', 'type' => 'hidden']) !!}
                </div>
                {!! Form::submit('Ara', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I couldn't build a query to search the "**related interactions**" for each selected "**drug**" , array those interactions and print them **only if an interaction_id exists twice** in array.

All help is appreciated. Thanks All !

Comment: I have no clue what you want to do. Maybe rephrase it and start with the question instead of the code.

Comment: What i want to do is probably very simple but i couldn't even understand my mistake here. I have a select2 dropdown list. I can choose multiple drug-ids from there. I want to pass those ids to my searchcontroller and use those ids in a query. In that query i want to look for interactions which are related to drugs by many to many relationship. I  may have passed the data to controller but i couldn't create a proper query for related models.